# Android Countdown Timer Thread.sleep();

Tags: java, android, timer, countdowntimer, thread-sleep

I am trying to create a circuit timer using the countdown timer. When the thread is sleeping I want the text to display "Change!" and this to display for 5 seconds before the countdown timer starts again. I am unsure how to get this working. I know the thread is sleeping and so wont display the "Change!" until after it has woke up again after the 5 seconds. But I cannot understand how to get it working the way I wish it to. Can anyone help me solve this issue?

```
public void onFinish()
{
    // Text to be displayed when thread is sleeping
    time.setText("Change!");
    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (numberOfCircuits != 15)
    {
        start();
        numberOfCircuits++;
    }
    else
    {
        countDownTimer.cancel();
    }
}
```

Comment: You must not make the `main thread` to sleep. thats bad :-/ Try to use android.os.Handler :-)

Comment: You should explain why you want the main thread to sleep. May be the same functionality/effect can be achieved without doing so. You might want to consider showing a Dialog that disappears after 5 secs.

Comment: @Neo I want the main thread to count down from 10 to 0. Once I get to zero I want the text to display "Change!" for 5 seconds and then repeat the countdown again for a max of 15 times.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making the main thread sleep(you are likely to get an ANR dialog), you can use a Timer which can notify you of your 5sec lapse and you can schedule your CountDownTimer again.

```
public void onFinish()
{
  // Text to be displayed when thread is sleeping
  time.setText("Change!");

  new Timer("Sleeper").schedule(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
      if (numberOfCircuits != 15)
      {
        start();
        numberOfCircuits++;
      }
      else
      {
        countDownTimer.cancel();
      }
    }

  }, 5000); // 5 sec delay

}
```